# How to add elements in a multi dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, beautifulsoup

I am **scraping** details of a website and I need to create a JSON object dynamically.How can I achieve this like the example I have provided.If not JSON then how can I make a multi-dimensional array from my code as well.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

urls = 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/'
url = requests.get(urls).text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
title = soup.find_all('a')

for i in title:
    
    if(i.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in i.text):
        urll = urls+i.text
    # arr.append(i.text)
        urll1 = requests.get(urll).text
        soupp1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll1, 'lxml')
        season = soupp1.find_all('a')
        print(i.text)
        for j in season:

            if(j.text != '../'and ".mp4" not in j.text):

                urlla = urll+j.text
                urll2 = requests.get(urlla).text
                soupp2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll2, 'lxml')
                quality = soupp2.find_all('a')
                print(j.text)
                for k in quality:
                    if(k.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in k.text):

                        urllb = urlla+k.text
                        urll3 = requests.get(urllb).text
                        soupp3 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll3, 'lxml')
                        episode = soupp3.find_all('a')
                        print(k.text)
                        for m in episode:
                            if(m.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in m.text):
                                print(m.text)
```

Series->Seasons->Quality->Episodes.

This is the flow chart of the JSON file that I wish to have.
The code I have written goes through nested links and finds all of the data that I need,I am not being able to make a multi-dimensional array out of it.

My code recursively opens all of the links and **scrapes** the text that I want. All I need to solve is how to add all of it in a nested fashion.

Comment: Where is your code related on "multi-dimensional array"?

Comment: That's the problem. I am not being able to understand how to add elements in multi dimensional array. My code recursively opens all of the links and scraps the text. I wish to add it in the nestled fashion in an array

Comment: Where is your recursive function?

Comment: Then try to post your desired output, an example with minimal data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python any sort of data can be stored into `list` and `dictionaries`, there is almost never a need for making multi-dimensional arrays or vectors.

`Series->Seasons->Quality->Episodes.`

Just by looking at your flowchart(as you call it), you can workaround as follows:

`episodes` will be a `list` within `Quality(dict)` within `Seasons(dict)` within `Series(dict)`

You have to give a read to making `dicts of dicts` and `dicts of lists` and how to store data in them in Python.

Answer (score 0):

- [endswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method returns True if a string ends with the specified suffix. If not, it returns False.
- [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) in-built function of Python is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.

**Ex.**

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

def _parse_website_text(url):
  res = requests.get(url).text
  soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
  return soup

main_url='http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/'
soup = _parse_website_text(main_url)
series = soup.find_all('a',href=True)

seriesJson = {}

for s in series:
  if ('../' in s.text or ".mp4" in s.text):
    continue

  series_key = s.text.strip().replace('/','')
  seriesJson[series_key] = {}
  soup1 = _parse_website_text(main_url+s['href'])
  seasons = soup1.find_all('a', href=True)

  for season in seasons:
    if ('../' in season['href'] or season.text.endswith(".mp4")):
      continue

    season_key = season.text.strip().replace('/','')
    seriesJson[series_key][season_key] = {}
    soup2 = _parse_website_text(main_url + s['href']+ season['href'])
    quality = soup2.find_all('a', href=True)

    for q in quality:
      if ('../' in q['href'] or q.text.endswith(".mp4")):
        continue

      quality_key = q.text.strip().replace('/','')
      seriesJson[series_key][season_key][quality_key] = []
      soup2 = _parse_website_text(main_url + s['href'] + season['href']+q['href'])
      episodes = soup2.find_all('a', href=True)

      for e in episodes:
        if '../' in e['href']:
          continue

        es_dict = dict(url=main_url + s['href'] + season['href']+q['href']+e['href'],title=e.text)
        seriesJson[series_key][season_key][quality_key].append(es_dict)

  print(seriesJson)
```

O/P:

```
{'12 Monkeys': {'S01': {'480p': [{'url': 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/12 Monkeys/S01/480p/12.Monkeys.S01E01.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv', 'title': '12.Monkeys.S01E01.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv'}, {'url': 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/12 Monkeys/S01/480p/12.Monkeys.S01E02.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv', 'title': '12.Monkeys.S01E02.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv'}, {'url': 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/12 Monkeys/S01/480p/12.Monkeys.S01E03.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv', 'title': '12.Monkeys.S01E03.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv'}, {'url': 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/12 Monkeys/S01/480p/12.Monkeys.S01E04.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv', 'title': '12.Monkeys.S01E04.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv'}, {'url': 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/12 Monkeys/S01/480p/12.Monkeys.S01E05.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv', 'title': '12.Monkeys.S01E05.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv'}, {'url': 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/12 Monkeys/S01/480p/12.Monkeys.S01E06.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv', 'title': '12.Monkeys.S01E06.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv'}, {'url': 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/12 Monkeys/S01/480p/12.Monkeys.S01E07.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv', 'title': '12.Monkeys.S01E07.480p.HDTV.LavinMovie.mkv'}]}}}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have solved my problem myself here is what I did.

```
    import requests
    import bs4 as bs
    import json
    urls = 'http://dl5.lavinmovie.net/Series/'
    url = requests.get(urls).text
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find_all('a')

    series = {}
    for i in title:

        if(i.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in i.text):
            urll = urls+i.text
        # arr.append(i.text)
            urll1 = requests.get(urll).text
            soupp1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll1, 'lxml')
            season = soupp1.find_all('a')
            Series = (i.text).replace("/", "")
            series[Series] = {}
          #  print(i.text)

            for j in season:

                if(j.text != '../'and ".mp4" not in j.text):

                    urlla = urll+j.text
                    urll2 = requests.get(urlla).text
                    soupp2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll2, 'lxml')
                    quality = soupp2.find_all('a')
                    Seasons = (j.text).replace("/", "")

                    series[Series][Seasons] = {}
                   # print(j.text)
                    for k in quality:
                        if(k.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in k.text):

                            urllb = urlla+k.text
                            urll3 = requests.get(urllb).text
                            soupp3 = bs.BeautifulSoup(urll3, 'lxml')
                            episode = soupp3.find_all('a')
                            Quality = (k.text).replace("/", "")
                            series[Series][Seasons][Quality] = []
                          #  print(k.text)
                            for m in episode:

                                if(m.text != '../' and ".mp4" not in m.text):
                                    series[Series][Seasons][Quality].append(urllb)

                            jsonfinal = json.dumps(series)
                            with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
                                json.dump(jsonfinal, outfile)
```

Thanks falco97.